# Is there a way to resize multiple objects with different sizes, to the same dimensions?

Tags: extrude, scale, dimensions

So I am very new to Blender and I am attempting to model a low poly P250, after a lot of struggle I had the wireframe outline, but when I looked at it in 3D view everything had different thicknesses, I've got no clue how to change all parts to the same dimensions. To an experienced user this must be painful to look at haha.

[image]

Comment: if those are different objects, you can go in the N panel > Item > Dimensions, and give them the same dimension on the chosen axis. If this is one object, you need to find an addon that will give you the dimensions of the selected mesh/edge, maybe check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86829/edit-mode-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

press TAB

select all by pressing "A"

press S to scale

now without touching anykey/mouse.. press X

and now move your mouse ... it will start scaling in X direction.