# Set dimensions in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, edges, dimensions

In object mode you can set the dimension in the item bar. But in edit mode you can't select something, like edges or faces and apply an specific dimension.

[image]

As far as I could search, I found this [Edit Mode Dimensions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86829/edit-mode-dimensions) , the solution is to download [Bforartists](https://www.bforartists.de/) a Blender Fork that includes this tool.

I also found this [How to set absolute bounding box dimensions of a group of selected elements (vertices, edges or faces)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/how-to-set-absolute-bounding-box-dimensions-of-a-group-of-selected-elements-ver/68678#68678) but that solution doesn't seem to work now as it is for an old version.

How do you set dimensions in edit mode?

Answer (score 2):

It's missing because there are only so many developers at the Foundation and so many hours in the day and nobody has made the case that this feature should have priority over the others in the long list of features they would like to implement. They don't copy back from the fork for the same reason: no people available to do it and all the other things they want.

This is not unique to Blender.  *Every* successful software project has a long list of desired features and far too few people to implement them all; so somebody has to decide what order to implement things in.

There is a forum, [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot), for suggesting features, and you can track various ToDo lists, like [this one for the User Interface](https://developer.blender.org/T55364) at the Blender Foundation that show what features they would like to add.  They're also pretty open about what they're working on and have planned.

Bforartists is an excellent fork but the developers who maintain it have different priorities than the developers who work at the foundation. That's why they forked it in the first place.  They do stay very current with the main tree, and if you like their approach to user interfaces, I strongly suggest using the fork.

Comment: That makes sense, i just thought that tool is kind of necesary if you want your shapes to have specific dimensions. I guess most of the people does not use blender for real life aplications, so they can go on with estimated sizes. Im using blender for 3D printing models and I need to set the correct sizes, so I am going to use Bforartists.

Comment: @Hornux There are other ways to get the correct dimensions in edit mode in Blender, and so people do use it for real life 3d printing applications.  But definitely in this case b4a has a clearer UI.