# Where is the dimensions option?

Tags: dimensions

I need this desperately but can't find it. Am I doing something wrong? 
[image]

Comment: dimensions of or for what? what setting are you talking about?

Comment: Oooh, yeah I just realised it's because i'm in edit mode. Thank you very much, it's working now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are in Edit mode. You can only set "dimensions" in object mode (same as with scale).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dimensions of the current selection in edit mode, although you have to install the free add-on that I wrote for the answer presented here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28015.

You can download the add-on directly from GitHub here: https://github.com/ekaj2/MeshTools

[image]