# Locking size of individual mesh part

Tags: modeling

I have an object with a lot of holes with the same size.

I want to make the object smaller, but also I want to save sizes of the holes that are part of the object.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots? It is hard to tell what you're asking with just words.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WkHtzDf

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question for you to add the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scaling the object, determine the amount of scaling of the holes required to "undo" that scaling. For example, if the object was scaled down by a factor of 0.9, use `1 / 0.9 = 1.111` as the scale factor to adjust the holes by.

To quickly scale all of the holes switch to use the pivot center "Individual Origins" and it should scale each hole separately.

You can get the add-on presented in this answer to verify that the dimensions of the holes are indeed the same: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28015.

[image]

[image]