# Get dimension of selected part of mesh?

Tags: dimensions

is there a way to get the dimensions (bounding-box scale) of a selected part of a mesh? Right now I have to do the following steps to get that information:

- duplicate the selected part of the mesh
- part it
- switch to object mode
- select the new object
- finally read the dimension in the right bar
- delete the object (cause I don't need it anymore)
- select the other object again
- switch back to edit mode to continue work ...

Since I have to do this very often I would welcome a shortcut or something ...

EDIT: the addon presented [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/how-to-set-absolute-bounding-box-dimensions-of-a-group-of-selected-elements-ver?rq=1) comes close to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately the panel closes every time I change the selection and has to be reopened via menu ...
Many thanks

Comment: The combination of min and max of x, y and z component of selected vert coordinates will give the 8 bbox coords.

Comment: just write a script that does exactly what you do and output the dimensions in console.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I think this should help. when you are in edit mode, turn on this edge/face infos from the N key menu. this will show the scales of the parts you select.

Comment: Hello Ashok, thanks for you help but this shows the individual edge-lengths. I guess I wasn't precise enough. The information I'm looking for is dimension of the whole selection (the bounding-box for the selection).